# Best string search algorithm around

Tags: c++, string, search

I have a code where in i compare a large data, say a source of a web page against some words in a file. What is the best algorithm to be used?

There can be 2 scenarios:

1. If I have a large amount of words to compare against the source, In which case, for a normal string search algorithm, it would have to take a word, compare against the data, take the next and compare against the data and so on until all is complete.
2. I have only a couple of words in the file and the normal string search would be ok, but still need to reduce the time as much as possible.

What algorithm is best? I know about Boyer-Moore and also Rabin-Karp search algorithms.
Although Boyer-Moore search seems fast, I would also like names of other algorithms and their comparisons.

Comment: Define "best algorithm".

Comment: fastest and worst case comparing time is not that worse...

Comment: Have you tried implementing BM and RK and compared them to a naive string search? Does the order of words matter?

Comment: Note that with string-searching algorithms, the algorithm with the better complexity can often not be the one with better real-world performance. It highly depends on your data-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, I think you probably want to construct a patricia trie (also called radix tree). Most importantly, lookup time would be O(k), where k is the max length of a string in the trie.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Boyer-Moore is to search a text (*several* words) within a text.

If all you want is identifying some individual words, then it's much easier to:

- put each *searched* word in a dictionary structure (whatever it is)
- look-up each word of the text in the dictionary

This most notably mean that you read the text as a stream, and need not hold it all in memory at once (which works great with the typical example of a file cursor).

As for the structure of the dictionary, I would recommend a simple hash table. Works great memory-wise compared to tree structures.